# Setting up multiple websites on a Linux server

Tags: server, php, mysql, directory

I currently have an Ubuntu server, on which I have set up a little website for an old project, it's written in HTML/CSS/JS, and now I'm working on a new web app written in PHP and MySQL.

I would like for both sites to be deployed. Right now, if I go to my IP address, by default it goes to the old site, its files directory is `/var/www/lifeonearth/html/{all files here}` and my new project is in `/var/www/webDarts/{php files here}`.

Can anyone tell me how I can access the new app? Do I have to setup a virtual host or something, because it has been a while since I used this thing, and I'm a bit rusty...

Comment: That's exactly what you need to do.  Google turned up this: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts   (Submitted as a reply, not an answer, since link-only answers are frowned upon. Hope it helps though.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we need to make a default.conf in the folder **/etc/apache2/sites-available**

The **default.conf** file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin foo@foo.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/default

  <Directory /var/www/default>
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/default-error.log

  # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
  # alert, emerg.
  LogLevel warn

  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/default-access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Now our default is configured, we can setup multiple websites, example of one:

The **foo.com.conf** file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName foo.com
  ServerAlias *.foo.com
  ServerAdmin administrator@foo.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/foo.com

  <Directory /var/www/foo.com>
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/foo_com-error.log

  # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
  # alert, emerg.
  LogLevel warn

  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/foo_com-access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Now we need to do `a2ensite foo.com` and `service apache2 reload`

If you want addional sites, just do the following:

1. cd /etc/apache2/sites-available
2. cp foo.com.conf new-domain.com.conf
3. vim new-domain.com.conf
   (replace all foo.com & foo_com with new-domain.com & new-domain_com)
4. mkdir /var/www/new-domain.com
5. place contents in /var/www/new-domain.com
6. a2ensite new-domain.com.conf
7. service apache2 reload

Let me know if it didn't work, I assume you know about user policy? (www-data, chmod 755 on /var/www?)

Comment: how do i access the site through ip, since i don't have a domain name, and is it a problem that i don't have an index.html or index.php page in the files?

Comment: @Reaper9806 - ServerAlias is what you should change, reading the [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#serveralias) would be handy.  And [urlmapping](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/urlmapping.html). Let me know if it worked out.